# Android Asset slicing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design, android

I am a Graphic Designer, I have designed an app and gave it to the developers, Now they are asking App assets in HDPI, XHDPI, XXHDPI how should i slice them? it should fit perfectly but i dont know the method.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581649/about-android-image-and-asset-sizes

Comment: Here's a calculator which may help: http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/

Answer (score 0):

It may be slightly easier to work at mdpi. For asset creation, hdpi is 1.5x those at mdpi, xhdpi is 2x, xxhdpi is 3x. So, for an asset that is 100px square, for example, you'll have assets which are (100px (m), 150px (h), 200px (xh), 300px (xxh)).

If you do need to work at hdpi as your base, create assets for xhdpi that are a third bigger and for xxhdpi that are twice as big.

I'd also suggest reading Google's design guidelines [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html).

They have some excellent resources [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/sticker-sheets-icons.html) including links to all their icons and helpful sticker sheets.

Comment: bro i want to know how would you know the icon size not hdpi size or mdpi ... for eg i am working in 480 x800 hdpi size and i have a icon, how can i  know the W & H  size of the icon